# What is the logic behind \@afterindentfalse when \@tempskipa <\z@?

Tags: sectioning, source

I am just looking to confirm what I suspect. Was this programmed to make any negative :

- have no vertical effect because nobody in their right mind would want overlapping text?
- Therefore disable indent in inline headings?

If there is more to add, please do! If I am wrong, please tell the real story behind this.

In the source2e document, the \@startsection has this code to deal with indentation on the line directly following a heading.

```
\@tempskipa #4\relax
\@afterindenttrue
\ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
  \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
\fi
```

Comment: The fourth argument to `\@startsection` is overloaded: a negative value means “no indentation in the paragraph following the title”, but the space is the absolute value.

Comment: You can also have a look at `ltsect.dtx`, which might---or might not---be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In source2e (or its component ltsect.dtx) you find this documented as

```
 \begin{macro}{\@startsection}

 The |\@startsection{|\meta{name}|}{|\meta{level}|}{|%
       \meta{indent}|}{|\meta{beforeskip}|}|\\
     |{|\meta{afterskip}|}{|\meta{style}|}*[|\meta{altheading}%
     |]{|\meta{heading}|}|
 command is the mother of all the user level sectioning commands.
 The part after the |*|, including the |*| is optional.

 \begin{description}
 \item[name:] e.g., 'subsection'
 \item[level:] a number, denoting depth of section -- e.g.,
                  chapter = 0, section = 1, etc.
 \item[indent:] Indentation of heading from left margin
 \item[beforeskip:] Absolute value = skip to leave above the heading.
                If negative, then paragraph indent of text following
                heading is suppressed.
 \item[afterskip:] if positive, then skip to leave below heading, else
                negative of skip to leave to right of run-in heading.
 \item[style:] Commands to set style. Since June 1996 release the
               \emph{last} command in this argument may be a command
                such as |\MakeUppercase| or |\fbox| that takes an
                argument. The section heading will be supplied as the
                argument to this command. So setting |#6| to, say,
                |\bfseries\MakeUppercase| would produce bold,
                uppercase headings.
 \end{description}
```

So a heading specification includes two lengths (before and after skips) and two boolean flags (display-or-inline and indent-or-not) but the flags are encoded by the sign of the skips (which is slightly unfortunate as it means that you can not use 0pt as the skip and still have a choice over the setting of the boolean)

So the code that you show negates `\@tempskipa` if it is negative so it ends up being the absolute value of the value specified in `\@startsection`, while at the same time setting the `\if@afterindent` flag to false to suppress paragraph indentation in the first paragraph after the heading.

Comment: I finally understand it. I know why I did not understand it the first time. TeX register variables can be set implicitly (the operator `=` is optional)-which makes it difficult for humans to read! The document could do a better job at explaining this. For example: `\@tempskipa`_OPERAND  `=`_OPERATOR_IMPLICIT  `-\@tempskipa`_OPERAND is the absolute value of `#4`, because this only occurs when `#4` is negative (`\ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@`). The operator is left out to save on token munching.

Comment: @macmadness86 in the latex kernel we omit _every_ token that was omittable `=` spaces, optional `{}` around arguments that are a single token. Doing so saved several hundred bytes which made the difference between latex2e being able to load into emtex and not fitting:-)

Comment: I understand. I made that last comment for posterity. Btw, I think the implicit aspects (utilized for sparing bytes) of the LaTeX kernel is the primary reason why the backend is hard for newcomers to grasp. I find that I had to learn how TeX processes everything before I could get something out of  `source2e`. Still, TeX has come a long way since 1978!